# Trying to access state from widget, probably using wrong design

Tags: flutter, widget, state

I'm learning flutter and trying to make a kind of MutableImage widget. The idea is to make a MutableImage StatefulWidget that would rebuild when a new image is provided. I try to avoid rebuilding the whole widget tree each time the image is changed because that seems overkill, and I plan to update the image several times per second. So I want to rebuild only that MutableImage widget.

So here is the code I have, with comments to explain where I'm stuck :

```
class MutableImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MutableImageState();
  }

  void updateImage(List<int> bytes) {
    // !!!!!! Would like to call this method here, but state is not available from Widget, which means I want to do something wrong, but not sure exactly how I should do it...
    // this.state.updateImage(bytes);
  }
}
class MutableImageState extends State<MutableImage> {
  List<int> _bytes;
  void updateImage(List<int> bytes) {
    setState(() {
      _bytes=bytes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if ((_bytes==null)||(_bytes.length==0)) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return Image.memory(_bytes);
  }
}
```

Then the idea was to use this widget like this for example in another stateful widget

```
MutableImage _mutableImage;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (_mutableImage == null) _mutableImage=MutableImage();
  return : Row( //using Row as an example, the idea is that the mutable Image is deep into a tree of widgets, and I want to rebuild only _mutableImage when image changes, not all widgets.
    children : <Widget>[
      child0, child1, _mutableImage, child3, child4
    ]
  );
}

void updateImage(List<int> bytes) {
  _mutableImage?.updateImage(bytes);
}
```

So is there a good way to do this ? I'm quite confused, thx for any help/hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place for an application of a `GlobalKey`. In the parent Widget of `MutableImage` make a global key and pass that to `MutableImage`. With that key you can access `MutableImage` state by using `.currentState` on the key and calling `updateImage`.

You'll have to add key as an argument of the `MutableImage` constructor and call `super(key: key)`. `updateImage` should also be moved the the state of `MutableImage`.

Key:

```
final GlobalKey<MutableImageState> _imageKey = GlobalKey<MutableImageState>();
```

Pass the key:

```
MutableImage(key: _imageKey);
```

Access the state:

```
_imageKey.currentState.updateImage();
```

Comment: Oh OK thx, that looks indeed like a very good solution. Let me test this and I'll accept the answer. [edit] it seems that the GlobalKey variable should use MutableImageState an not MutableImage (edited your answer).

Comment: @jptsetung Yeah sorry about that it should be the state.